# como passar um array com N argumentos para um bind_param dentro de uma classe?

Tags: php

Estou tentando desenvolver uma classe global para paginação

Segue o codigo:

```
class Pager {
private $Sql;
private $Limit;
private $ArgType;
private $Page;
private $Arguments;
private $ArgNumber;
private $Connect;
private $result=array();
public function setSql($Sql){
    $this->Sql=$Sql;
    return false;
}
public function setLimit($Limit){
    $this->Limit=$Limit;
    return false;
}
public function setArguments(){
    $this->Arguments=func_get_args();
    $this->ArgNumber=func_num_args();
    return false;
}
public function setArgType($ArgType){
    $this->ArgType=$ArgType;
    return false;
}
public function setConnect($Connect){
    $this->Connect=$Connect;
    return false;
}
public function setPage($Page){
    $this->Page= isset($Page)?$Page:1;
    return false;
}
private function countRegister(){
    $Pager = $this->Connect->prepare($this->Sql);
    switch ($this->ArgNumber){
        case 1:
            $Pager->bind_param($this->ArgType,$this->Arguments[0]);
        break;
        case 2:
            $Pager->bind_param($this->ArgType,$this->Arguments[0],$this->Arguments[1]);
        break;
        case 3:
            $Pager->bind_param($this->ArgType,$this->Arguments[0],$this->Arguments[1],$this->Arguments[2]);
        break;
        case 4:
            $Pager->bind_param($this->ArgType,$this->Arguments[0],$this->Arguments[1],$this->Arguments[2],$this->Arguments[3]);
        break;
        case 5:
            $Pager->bind_param($this->ArgType,$this->Arguments[0],$this->Arguments[1],$this->Arguments[2],$this->Arguments[3],$this->Arguments[4]);
        break;
    }
    $Pager->execute();
    $Pager->store_result();
    return $Pager->num_rows;
    $Pager->close();
}
private function countPages($NumReg){
    return ceil($NumReg/$this->Limit);
}
private function prevPage(){
    if($this->Page>1)
        return $this->Page-1;
    else
        return false;
}
private function nextPage(){
    if($this->Page<$this->result['Pages'])
        return $this->Page+1;
    else
        return false;
}
private function getStart(){
    return ($this->Page-1)*$this->Limit;
}
public function execPager(){
    $this->result['Pages'] = $this->countPages($this->countRegister());
    $this->result['PrevPage'] = $this->prevPage();
    $this->result['NextPage'] = $this->nextPage();
    $this->result['Start'] = $this->getStart();
    $this->result['Limit'] = $this->Limit;
    return false;
}
public function getPager(){
    return $this->result;
}
```

}

Porem na `private function execPage()` eu nao vejo um mode de fazer o `bind_param` com o `array` que pego na função `setArguments` a unica forma foi usando um case com possibilidades pré definidas

Alguma sugestão de como passar esses parâmetros para a função e poder executar dessa forma?

Estou usando mysqli e a classe está em estágio inicial, na função `setArgument` vou passa N argumentos e colocar o tipo de argumento pela função `setArgType` sendo que a mesma sera uma `string` depois vou colocar dentro do `bind_param` dessa forma

```
$Pager->bind_param($this->setArgType, [Todos os N argumentos da setArguments]);
```

Comment: Cade o `bind_param()` os get's(sql, limit, connect) não deveriam retorar algo no lugar de atribuir?

Comment: na verdade o nome está contrario a utilização, estou fazendo isso meio as pressas hoje, mas a intenção é atribuir valores, como o objetivo é deixar funcionando primeiro pra aprimorar depois eu não parei pra pensar no nome correto das variaveis

Comment: vou atualizar para set

Comment: agora ficou de uma forma mais compreensiva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não vou entrar no mérito de responsabilidade de objetos pois esse não é o objetivo da pergunta mas o que você tem implementado não faz sentido.

Sua classe não tem nenhum *setter*, método público para que dados possam ser definidos para a classe trabalhar. O mais próximo disso seria o *getArguments()* que dá a entender que alguma coisa vai ser **retornada** e não **definida**.

Além de todas as várias alterações que você precisará fazer para tornar essa classe plausível de se utilizar seria algo assim:

```
class Paginador {

    // ...

    private $arguments = array();

    public function setArguments( $argument, $value ) {

        $this -> arguments[ $argument ] = $value;
    }

    public function getAruments() {
        return $this -> arguments;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Feito isso sua classe já pode ser manipulada externamente através da instância do objeto.

Agora, no que tange o escopo da pergunta.

Primeiro você tem de definir de onde esse `bind_param` virá. É de uma classe externa? De uma classe nativa?

Supondo que seja sua resposta seja a [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) você primeiro deve preparar o *statement*, isto é, a string SQL e si, definindo os devidos *placehodlers*, sejam eles nomeados (precedidos por dois-pontos) ou indexados (apenas interrogações) e, no seu método `execPage()` você itera os argumentos da sua propriedade de argumentos e a cada iteração você vincula o novo argumento:

```
class Paginador {

    // ...

    private function execPage() {

        // Prepare statement

        foreach( $this -> arguments as $argument => $value ) {

            if( is_string( $value ) && ! is_numeric( $value ) ) {

                $dataType = PDO::PARAM_STR;

            } else {

                $dataType = PDO::PARAM_INT;
            }

            $stmt -> bindParam( $argument, $value, $dataType );
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

> O exemplo didático acima assume que o *statement* preparado esteja na variável **$stmt**

Basicamente é isso, mas você REALMENTE precisa estudar melhor Orientação a Objetos porque simplesmente jogar idéias numa classe não é OOP.

Uma dica: Evite func_get_args() sempre que possível. Essa função só deve ser usada quando REALMENTE você não sabe quantos argumentos serão informados para uma determinada função / método E não existe outra fora melhor de fazê-lo.

nesse cenário, a melhor forma de fazer seria informar um array com pares chave/valor ou usar de *Fluent Interfaces*.

Comment: Esse [bind_param](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) está com cara de mysqli.

Comment: Grandes chances, só mencionei a PDO porque nunca mexi com a MySQLi

Comment: editei a postagem, vi que a forma que escrevi ficou realmente confusa e agora creio que está mais compreensivel, não vi uma forma melhor de passar os argumentos alem de func_get_args() ja que podem ter N argumentos nessa função

Comment: Quando eu respondi eu procurei abranger inclusive uma futura edição então, sendo assim, o que foi dito ainda é válido e permanece meu conselho de você estudar melhor Orientação a Objetos e os princípios dela decorrentes. Você vai ver que, por exemplo, as tarefas relacionadas ao banco de dados não devem estar dentro da classe de paginação e sim em outra classe, à parte, e o objeto dessa classe seria injetado na classe de Paginação.

Comment: Mesmo assim não vejo uma forma de fazer o bind_param no mysqli, vejo que no PDO é possivel, mas o mesmo não tem se aplicado ao mysqli

Comment: É basicamente a mesma coisa. A MySQLi também tem uma abordagem "orientada a objetos" Ali no segundo código basta que a variável **$stmt** seja o retorno de um MySQLi::prepare() de sucesso.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto editei a pergunta com o código que cheguei atualmente... e o bind_param do PDO pode ser feito em linha enquanto no mysqli não, tenho que colocar todos os itens em uma unica linha

Comment: Se você checar a documentação da MySQLi pode ver que você **deve** passar uma variável (segundo argumento) e também **pode** passar duas, três, quatro... nos argumentos seguintes. Pela descrição do manual dá a entender que o que você informar para **$types** será aplicado para todas as variáveis. Isso é errado pois pode fazer um *double* ser tratado como um *int*. Sendo assim, é mais interessante fazer como no *foreach* da resposta, mas usando a função correspondente ao invés da PDO.